# Apache camel multiple endpoints

Tags: xml, groovy, apache-camel, spring-camel

I do a sql select and save the data in CSV.
Here i would like to do is sending the sql result to two endpoints.

I am using camel version 2.12.3

I tried with multicast but it doesn't work for the seconde endpoint.
I have the sql result only in first file but not the seconde

```
<to uri="sql:{{export.select.query}}?dataSource=selectDataSource" />
    <marshal>
        <csv autogenColumns="true" delimiter="|" />
    </marshal>
        <multicast stopOnException="true">
            <to uri="file:{{export.select.dir}}?fileName=${property.exportSelectFileName}_exportSelect.csv&amp;charset=utf-8" />
            <to uri="file:{{export.select_2.dir}}?fileName=exportSelect_${property.exportSelectFileName}.csv&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append" />
        
    </multicast>
```

Do you have other suggestion ? Otherwise is there any possiblity to do it with groovy ?

Comment: you can also remove the multicast entirely if you don't require the export to be parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wiretap to duplicate the message and send it to the first endpoint.
Or put the body in a property and get it after the first endpoint call.
The différence is on your error handling strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I found this below and it works fine for me

```
<recipientList>
     <constant>file:{{export.select.dir}}?fileName=${property.exportSelectFileName}_exportSelect.csv&amp;charset=utf-8,file:{{export.select_2.dir}}?fileName=exportSelect_${property.exportSelectFileName}.csv&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append </constant>
</recipientList>
```